# Changing the deployment provider codebase in a ClickOnce application without rebuilding it

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, clickonce

Is it possible to change the deploymentPorvider codebase location in a ClickOnce *.application config file without rebuilding the installer?

Currently I am getting the following exception:

```
    System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (SignatureValidation)
    - Manifest XML signature is not valid.
    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ValidateSignature(Stream s)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
    --- Inner Exception ---
    System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException
    - The digital signature of the object did not verify.

    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Deployment.Internal.CodeSigning.SignedCmiManifest.Verify(CmiManifestVerifyFlags verifyFlags)
        at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ValidateSignature(Stream s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible! You can use MageUI.exe or Mage.exe (cmd line tool) to modify that file. If you use mage, then mage can handle a lot of the details that need to happen to make sure all the files are in a consistent state. Here's a [general link on mage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhctdw55(v=vs.100).aspx), and here's [another link that talks about the deployment provider specifically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480721.aspx#adminc_topic21)  (see the section called *Setting and Changing the Deployment Provider*)